# will auto synthesize with @property(copy) NSString *string do auto copy?

Tags: objective-c

Say if I have a property with ARC and auto-synthesize:

```
@interface A: NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *Name;
@end
```

Now when using this property, will it do a copy automatically, or I have to do a manual copy?

Like

```
A *a = [A new];
NSString *str = @"hello";
a.name = str; // or a.name = [str copy]?
```

Comment: auto synthesize works the same way as manual synthesize - it will generate a getter and a setter according to the property declaration. If the property is `copy` then the setter will copy.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Marking property `copy` will work for mutable instances.
Basically you don't need to copy immutable instances (like NSString).

Comment: Correct answer, but incorrect code. str is created via string literal, so it with great possibility will be optimized in a way that copying it will return the same string instance (not speaking about immutable objects which are usually just returned (retained under mrc)). i.e. [str copy] == str.

Comment: I just want to say, the code is not working, still get the same address if I don't do copy, using string literal. NSMutableString can work. suggest you edit the code

Comment: To check, whether an instance is of an immutable class, you would need a runtime check, because the mutable versions are subclasses. So you do the copy in every case.

Comment: Not sure who downvote the answer, I don't see a reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

The synthesized version will include a copy itself. (But there is no really copy for instances of `NSString`, because they are immutable.) You do not need to do that.

To the Q in the comment below:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString*)name
{
  _name = [name copy];
}
```

Take care: You have to do the copy, even the parameter is typed to `NSString *`, because one could pass a reference to an instance of the mutable subclass `NSMutableString`.

Comment: If I have to write the setter of it, then I should do a manual copy, right?

Comment: @Wingzero Yes, you should implement the semantics promised by the declaration. I added code.